# Flutter - Align elements in Row and Column

Tags: flutter, android-layout, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a kind of custom App bar and I'm struggling with aligning  the elements correctly.

Pretty sure the solution should be simple but I feel like missing something.

I would like the result to be the following:

[image]

Code I've tried so far:

```
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
 Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
  InkWell(
   onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context);},
    child:Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
   ),
 ],),                      
 Column(children: [
  Container(child: Text("text"))),                                           
 ], crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center),
],)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be achieved very simply:

```
Row(
  children: [
    InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
    const Expanded(child: Center(child: Text("text"))),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Text("text"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: also, you can provide some `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),` for better view.